# How to reload JSP with changed actionbean variable using Stripes

Tags: javascript, jsp, stripes

I am new to working with Stripes. I have a dropdown ("show ## recordrs per page") and a paginated table on the JSP page and I want to display as many records per page in this table, as the value selected in the dropdown.

The action bean has a variable "recordsPerPage" and I am not able to figure out a way to set the value of this variable and reload the table, so as to change the number of records that are displayed per page. Please help.

---- Additional Info -----

The table that I use is a displaytag table, which accepts a PaginatedList. This table is within a stripes form.

-- EDIT:

What I did is, I added a `<stripes:hidden/>` with the name "recordsPerPage" and set the value to be the number of records I want to display. I also added a `<stripes:submit>` to the same form. The "name" attribute of this submit button is the method name of the action bean I have to call. When I click on this button, I am able to do what I want. But now, I am unable to do it through javascript. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some reason, calling `Dom.get('submitButton').submit()` or `Dom.get('myFormId').submit()` does not fulfill the intended purpose. Taking a clue from being able to do what I wanted from the submit button click, I made this submit button hidden and the called click() on this button from javascript. Thus `Dom.get('submitButton').click()` produces the intended result. If someone can give me the explanation of why the submit method did not result in expected behavior, that'll be great.